# A finite p-group question: can this happen?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let all groups here be finite $p$--groups.

Given $K<H$, let $r(K,H)$ be the smallest $r$ such that there exists a chain of subgroups $K=L_0 \lhd L_1 \lhd \cdots \lhd L_r = H$, such that each $L_i/L_{i-1}$ is cyclic.

**Question**: Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.  If $K_1$ and $K_2$ are subgroups of $H$ that are conjugate in $G$, does it follow that $r(K_1,H) = r(K_2,H)$?

As in the last [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334948/a-finite-2-group-containing-the-dihedral-group-of-order-16) I posed, a minimal counterexample would have $G = \langle H,g\rangle$, and $H$ not normal in $G$.

Comment: Your title asks "can this happen?", while your body asks (essentially) "must this happen?"  Could a better (as more specific) title be something like "Lengths of composition-type series for conjugate subgroups of finite $p$-groups"?  Also, I added a link to what I suppose is the last question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does not follow. Let $G=Z_4\wr Z_2$, or equivalently $$G=\langle a,b,t|a^4=b^4=[a,b]=t^2=1, a^t=b\rangle.$$ Let $H=\langle a,b^2\rangle$, $K_1=\langle a^2\rangle$, and $K_2=\langle b^2\rangle$. Then $K_1^t=K_2$, $r(K_1,H)=2$, and $r(K_2,H)=1$.

Comment: Thanks!  (Oh man, I should have thought of that.)